# Running RoR application in Windows, which was developed in Linux

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git

I have a RoR application working in Linux environment. I have to move that to windows environment. When I run

```
bundle exec rails server
```

I see this error

```
There was a Errno::ENOENT while loading omniauth-cas.gemspec:
No such file or directory - git ls-files -- bin/* from
```

When I opened the files, I saw these lines

```
gem.executables   = `git ls-files -- bin/*`.split("\n").map{ |f| File.basename(f) }
gem.files         = `git ls-files`.split("\n")
gem.test_files    = `git ls-files -- {test,spec,features}/*`.split
```

In these lines, I can understand that `ls-files` is a Linux command, which never work in Windows. With what should I replace this statement so that it runs in windows?

Comment: `ls-files` is not a linux command. It is an argument of the `git` command.

Comment: did you get any errors after running `bundle install` ?

Comment: Do you have Git installed on your Windows machine? If you are using Bundler 1.3, and run `bundle package --all` on your Linux machine, it will immediately evaluate the `gemspec`, and you shouldn't encounter this issue when the app is moved to the Windows machine. See this `bundler` issue for more information: https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/2287.

Answer (score 0):

Start by figuring out what your current working directory is for your running script.
Add this line at the beginning:

`puts Dir.pwd`.

This will tell you in which current working directory ruby is running your script. You will most likely see it's not where you assume it is. Then make sure you're specifying pathnames properly for windows. See the docs here how to properly format pathnames for windows:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html

Then either use Dir.chdir to change the working directory to the place where text.txt is, or specify the absolute pathname to the file according to the instructions in the IO docs above. That SHOULD do it...

Adding a 3rd solution which might be the most convenient one if you're putting the text files among your script files:

`Dir.chdir(File.dirname(__FILE__))`

This will automatically change the current working directory to the same directory as the .rb file that is running the script.